# Check box in gridview with button

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In button click event how can I check all check boxes in gridview?
I dont need header checkbox.

Please provide your knowledge

awaiting your response....

Thanks

Comment: or is javascript also an option, because IMO I think that would be best

Comment: Asking the exact same question again won't get you anywhere. Exact duplicate - closing.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938827/gridview-with-checkbox ,, And,, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932621/how-to-check-all-check-box-using-button-in-outside-the-gridview ,, 
And ,, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938232/without-postback-when-i-select-checkbox ,, And ,, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921347/check-box-in-gridview-with-button ,, And ,, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921100/checkbox-checked-when-button-click

Comment: oh..and all above "duplicates" posted by the same user :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a class to all your grid row check boxes and use the below script to get them all.

```
function getElementsByClass(searchClass,node,tag) {
    var classElements = new Array();
    if ( node == null )
        node = document;
    if ( tag == null )
        tag = '*';
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var elsLen = els.length;
    var pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+searchClass+"(\\s|$)");
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
        if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) ) {
                classElements[j] = els[i];
                j++;
        }
    }
    return classElements;
}
```

And you've to call it this way:

```
var messages = getElementsByClass("childbox");
```

Assign a class **`childbox`** to grid row child box.

```
document.getElementById("parentbox").onclick  = function() {
for(var index=0; index < messages.length; index++) {
 // prompt the content of the div
 //message[index].checked = (message[index].checked) ? false : true;
}
}
```

you'll assign the **`parentbox`** class to the parent checkbox which is in grid header.

You don't need to define them - **`parentbox`** and **`childbox`**.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input id="btncheckall" type="button" value="select all" />
```

add `click` event handler to button above (with jQuery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){

    $("#btncheckall").click(function(){

      $("#gridview input:checkbox").attr("checked","checked");

    });

  });
</script>
```

or you can use checkbox.
this is a checkbox outside gridview

```
<input id="checkall" type="checkbox" />
```

add `change` event handler to checkbox above (with jQuery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){

    $("#checkall").change(function(){

      $("#gridview input:checkbox").val( $(this).val() );

    });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

C#
Let's say you have a check all button

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" Text="SelectAll" 
AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged" />
```

and in that click event you would do something like:

```
protected void chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CheckBox chk;   //assuming your gridview id=GridView1

   foreach (GridViewRow rowItem in GridView1.Rows) 
  {   
     chk = (CheckBox)(rowItem.Cells[0].FindControl("chk1")); 
     chk.Checked =((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
   }
}
```

javascript approach:

```
<script language="javascript">

function SelectAllCheckboxes(spanChk){

// Added as ASPX uses SPAN for checkbox
var oItem = spanChk.children;
var theBox= (spanChk.type=="checkbox") ? 
    spanChk : spanChk.children.item[0];
xState=theBox.checked;
elm=theBox.form.elements;

for(i=0;i<elm.length;i++)
  if(elm[i].type=="checkbox" && 
          elm[i].id!=theBox.id)
  {
    //elm[i].click();
   if(elm[i].checked!=xState)
     elm[i].click();
   //elm[i].checked=xState;
  }
 }
</script>
```

Checkbox field as so:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" Text="SelectAll" 
onclick="javascript:SelectAllCheckboxes(this);" />
```

Comment: ya its working whwn the check box is in outside the grid but inside it doesnt work

Comment: which one did you use?javascript or c#?

Answer (score 1):

Hai Dominic,
  If you want javascript look at this
https://web.archive.org/web/20210304130956/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052406-1.aspx#postadlink

or
[Check box in gridview with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921347/check-box-in-gridview-with-button)

Answer (score 1):

Jquery can make this easier.  Hook into the external boxes onslected event, and inside there iterate the grid boxes selecting them all.

This is a great example of the evils of asp.net and how it's use by new developers really cripples them into thinking that all processing and interaction takes place server side, and all sorts of crazy hacks take place to maintain this illusion.  It's backwards and insane.

Comment: im new in jquery pls explain or give solution ...
can we do it by using javascript?

Comment: Jquery is built on JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate><asp:CheckBox ID="SelectUnSelectAllCheckBox" runat="server" /></HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate><asp:CheckBox ID="SelectCheckBox" runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <!-- Other columns are omitted -->
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("input[id$='SelectUnSelectAllCheckBox']").change(function() {
            $("input[id$='SelectCheckBox']").attr("checked", this.checked);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i didnt used header template
outside the grid?

Comment: It's possible to put `SelectUnSelectAllCheckBox` on everywhere you want.

Comment: how to call this script in client side

Comment: @Mehdi- this would definitely work, but should add alternative to check all to deselect all if already checked,@Domnic- this is a jquery solution, just a note: so you would have to include the jquery plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) you could use the $('input:checkbox') selector so something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#NameOfButtonToSelectAll').click( function() {
      $('input:checkbox').each( function() {
        this.checked = !this.checked;
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: how can i call this function in client side

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check it out and let me know when you got it worked.

Using Javascript :

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/281/check-uncheck-checkboxes-in-gridview-using-javascript/

Using Serverside Script: (VB.Net)

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145756/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052406-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#SelectAll').click(function(){
  var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
  var allCheckboxes = $('table input:checkbox');
  if(checked)
      allCheckboxes.attr('checked','checked');
  else
      allCheckboxes.removeAttr('checked');
});
```

You probably want to change the selectors, assuming you have a class for your grid and checkbox.

Comment: how ca i call this function in my checkbox 
id="chk1"
gridview checkbox id="gridchk"

Comment: You'll have easier time working with a CSSClass - those IDs are changed on the client side. You can probably do `$("[id$='chk1']")`, but again, working with a class is simpler.